# What is `~sys`? It lists the content of `/dev`

Tags: debian, filesystems

In `bash`, when I type `cd ~sys` anywhere, I end up in `/dev`. In `zsh` it stays as `~sys` in the prompt but contains `/dev`

I've checked on Kubuntu 22.04, Ubuntu 20.04, Raspbian 9.13.

Googling does not yield any results.

Comment: `echo ~sys` is probably clearer than `cd ~sys`.

Comment: @TobySpeight Actually I was just typing `~sys` and because I'm using `zsh` this left me in a directory named `~sys` which I could not locate anywhere but seemed to mirror `/dev`, see Gilles' answer. I later edited the question because I mistakenly said that this would happen in `bash` and in `zsh`, while it only happened in `zsh`. Yet in `bash` I ended up in `/dev` when `cd`-ing into `~sys`, which was also not clear to me why. I don't know why I ended up typing `~sys` on my machine in the first place.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When you enter `cd ~sys` you are changing to the home directory of the user `sys`. Just like `cd ~roaima` would change to the home directory for user `roaima`. A shortcut to your own home directory is simply `~`, so you may already know about using it for that.

In the password file (`grep '^sys:' /etc/passwd` or more generically `getent passwd sys`) you can see the home directory for `sys` is `/dev`:

```
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

which shows why `cd ~sys` changes you to the directory `/dev`.

Your original question mentioned just entering `~sys` without a verb. In this instance the shell translated `~sys` to its home directory, `/dev` and then tried to run it as a program. Obviously the directory can't be a program so the attempt failed:

```
~sys
-bash: /dev: Is a directory

/dev
-bash: /dev: Is a directory
```

If you are running a shell such as `bash` you can override this behaviour and have the shell treat attempted execution of a directory as an indication to change into that directory (i.e. implied `cd`):

```
shopt -s autocd
~sys               # → "cd -- /dev"
pwd                # → "/dev"

~                  # → "cd -- /home/roaima"
pwd                # → "/home/roaima"
```

See [Are there any caveats in using shopt -s autocd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/646800/100397) for further discussion.

Answer (score 11):

`~foo` expands to the home directory of the user `foo`. This is a feature of almost every modern shell including bash, zsh, more generally all POSIX-compliant shells, BusyBox ash, (t)csh (where it originated) and fish.

Unix systems have a number of system accounts, some for good reason, others largely historical. These system accounts have a home directory, even though they never log in: that's largely historical (and I'm not sure if leaving the field blank is properly supported, so they have to have something there anyhow, although it can be something like `/nonexistent`). Debian systems happen to have a system user called `sys`, which I think hasn't been used for years (decades?) but is still present for backward compatibility. The home directory of that user is `/dev`. So `~sys` expands to `/dev` in the shell and many other programs, just like `~daniel` expands to `/home/daniel` (or whatever your username and home directory are).

In zsh, if (like most people) you include the `%~` [prompt escape sequence](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Shell-state) in your prompt, then your prompt includes the current directory (possibly abbreviated). If the current directory is under your home directory, that part is abbreviated to `~`. Zsh takes this further and also abbreviates other directories that can be abbreviated through [tilde expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion). In particular, if you've previously referred to some user's home directory with the `~foo` syntax, then zsh remembers that this directory can be abbreviated as `~foo`.

Zsh calls this feature [static named directories](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Static-named-directories). The place where zsh remembers the named directories is the directory hash table, which you can access with the builtins [`hash -d`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-hash-1) and [`unhash -d`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-unhash).

```
darkstar% PS1='%~%% '
~% cd /dev
/dev% hash -d              # No known directory abbreviations so far
/dev% echo ~sys            # Let's use ~sys
~sys% hash -d              # Now ~sys=/dev, seen in the hash table and the prompt
sys=/dev
~sys% unhash -d sys        # Forget the abbreviation
/dev%                      # Now the prompt is no longer "abbreviated"
```

Annoyingly, zsh considers `~foo` to be a worthwhile abbreviation of the home directory of `foo` if the “abbreviation” is shorter *or as long* as the original string. I make it forget named directories that are of equal length:

```bash
function chpwd_prompt {
    # If a user foo has the home directory /bar and length("foo") <
    # length("bar") then zsh shows `/bar' as `~foo'. If length("foo")
    # = length("bar") then zsh still favors `~foo', but I want `/bar'.
  if [[ ${(%):-%~} == \~* && ${#${(%):-%~}} -eq $#PWD ]]; then
    unhash -d -- ${${${(%):-%~}%%/*}#\~}
  fi
}
chpwd_functions+=(chpwd_prompt)
```

This code can obviously be adapted to different preferences, for example to only ever abbreviate directories under `/home`, or only `~` itself (though for that it's easier to start from `%/` and replace your home directory only).

Comment: That's interesting. zsh is my default shell, so I was irritated by being in `~sys` after (accidentally?) typing `~sys`, which defaults to `cd`-ing into the directory. My first thought was that this could be a rootkit (on Windows rootkits would have such an effect of mounting odd paths), but then checking with bash and on other systems made me think that it's something else.

Comment: I wonder if there's any system where a stock account would have an _empty_ home directory field, and thus have "no" home directory at all. Somehow, it feels like it would be likely to cause more issues than it'd be worth, with some program down the road not expecting it. Some system accounts on the Debian I looked at have `/nonexistent` as their home.

Comment: @ilkkachu [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_435) says “If the initial working directory field is null, the interpretation of that field is implementation-defined.” I think in practice that means the user's initial directory would be the root directory, but I don't know if `~username` would expand to an empty string — I guess it would though, why wouldn't it?

Comment: Technically, that feature comes from csh, copied by the Korn shell (and specified by POSIX and found in POSIX shells as a result) but not by the Bourne shell

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', yes at least Bash and zsh something like `HOME=; echo ~/foo` prints just `/foo`. But then `chdir("")` itself seems to give a "No such file or directory" error at least on Linux, something that might get hit if actually trying to login to an account with an empty home directory. (I can't recall if the meaning of an empty path was defined somewhere, though.)

Comment: @ilkkachu see https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1047. IIRC, on some systems `chdir("")` does the same as `chdir(".")` (noop)

Answer (score 7):

The term `~sys` refers to the home directory of the user `sys`. As can be seen by running `getent passwd sys` - its home directory is listed as `/dev`.

I've looked, but I'm not actually sure what is that user account - it is obviously a system account (as can be seen by its low id number of 3), and it belongs to a `sys` group (which is likewise a "system account group"), but on a modern Ubuntu installation it does not own or have access to any file or process. It may be a legacy thing.

Answer (score -2):

Indeed.  For stuff that needs some extra access, but not full root, adm was generally for "administrative" uses and sys for "system" uses.  Which is rather vague, but really that's because these weren't strictly standardized.

Apparently in Arch Linux in present day, adm gets access to files in /var/log that regular users can't read, and sys has access to cups administration (which I must say is a little weird, lp is "line printer" and the traditional user/group for printing-related stuff.)

In Debian/Ubuntu sys is not used at all, probably uucp and several of those others aren't either, but they are traditional and so left in.  (With no password, shell set to nologin, and no files owned by them, they are effectively inert anyway so leaving them in doesn't do any harm even from a theoretical security standpoint.)

Comment: None of this seems to address the question actually asked.

Comment: Well, I mean the question is what is ~sys and it discusses why sys and adm even exist.